# Is it necessary to update NodeJS - MySQL (Callback) Connections to MariaDB (Promises/async-await)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I'm kind of new to NodeJS development and enjoyed all this new development learning. I'm building kind of a CMS using NodeJS v10.15 and MySQL 8.0 in Windows 10. I havent'd had any problems during my development on Windows, but recently i started to export my NodeJS CMS to a Raspberry Pi4 (Raspbian), because i wanted to know if i could started loading different instances of my CMS on Raspberry and it worked.

However when i was trying to stablish connection between NodeJS and MySQL (actually MariaDB), i noticed that MariaDB (MySQL is not available on Raspbian) connections used Promises and Async/await functions and not the classic Callback function that is used on MySQL. I had to start looking for a module that allowed the MySQL classic Connection to avoid rewriting all of my CMS only for Raspberry and found a compatibility module called mariadb/callback.

So at this point i'm not sure about the way i'm developing my CMS with MySQL, because i see that the official database product is MariaDB on Promises and Async/Await, and the MySQL way is only for compatibility, like an emergency option that someday will be shut down.

Should i rewrite my CMS to MariaDB Promises and Async/Await to replace the MySQL classic connection?
Thanks in advance for your answers, it's really important for me.